# Problem Showing data from API in dropdown menu flutter

Tags: flutter, drop-down-menu

I try to populate a dropdown with internet data from an API and I'm on it for a while now and I seriously need some help. here is the code the Json and the output I have.

My code,

```
Welcome welcomeFromJson(String str) => Welcome.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String welcomeToJson(Welcome data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class Welcome {
Welcome({
    this.success,
    this.cssclass,
    this.events,
});

int success;
String cssclass;
List<Event> events;

factory Welcome.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Welcome(
    success: json["success"],
    cssclass: json["cssclass"],
    events: List<Event>.from(json["events"].map((x) => Event.fromJson(x))),
);

Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "success": success,
    "cssclass": cssclass,
    "events": List<dynamic>.from(events.map((x) => x.toJson())),
};
}

class Event {
Event({
    this.idEvenement,
    this.titreCourtEvenement,
    this.titreEvenement,
    this.idLangue,
    this.nomLangue,
    this.flagLangue,
    this.idSociete,
    this.dateDebutEvenement,
    this.dateFinEvenement,
    this.archiverEvenement,
    this.masquerEvenement,
    this.isAdhesion,
    this.idUser,
    this.imageAgendaEvenement,
    this.imageLogo,
});

String idEvenement;
String titreCourtEvenement;
String titreEvenement;
String idLangue;
String nomLangue;
String flagLangue;
String idSociete;
DateTime dateDebutEvenement;
DateTime dateFinEvenement;
String archiverEvenement;
String masquerEvenement;
String isAdhesion;
String idUser;
String imageAgendaEvenement;
String imageLogo;

factory Event.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Event(
    idEvenement: json["idEvenement"],
    titreCourtEvenement: json["titreCourtEvenement"],
    titreEvenement: json["titreEvenement"],
    idLangue: json["idLangue"],
    nomLangue: json["nomLangue"],
    flagLangue: json["flagLangue"],
    idSociete: json["idSociete"],
    dateDebutEvenement: DateTime.parse(json["dateDebutEvenement"]),
    dateFinEvenement: DateTime.parse(json["dateFinEvenement"]),
    archiverEvenement: json["archiverEvenement"],
    masquerEvenement: json["masquerEvenement"],
    isAdhesion: json["isAdhesion"],
    idUser: json["idUser"],
    imageAgendaEvenement: json["imageAgendaEvenement"],
    imageLogo: json["imageLogo"],
);

Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "idEvenement": idEvenement,
    "titreCourtEvenement": titreCourtEvenement,
    "titreEvenement": titreEvenement,
    "idLangue": idLangue,
    "nomLangue": nomLangue,
    "flagLangue": flagLangue,
    "idSociete": idSociete,
    "dateDebutEvenement": dateDebutEvenement.toIso8601String(),
    "dateFinEvenement": dateFinEvenement.toIso8601String(),
    "archiverEvenement": archiverEvenement,
    "masquerEvenement": masquerEvenement,
    "isAdhesion": isAdhesion,
    "idUser": idUser,
    "imageAgendaEvenement": imageAgendaEvenement,
    "imageLogo": imageLogo,
};
}

 class Test2 extends StatefulWidget {
  const Test2({ Key key }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _Test2State createState() => _Test2State(); 
}

 class _Test2State extends State<Test2> {
   Future<dynamic> getSWData() async {
   var res = await http.get(Uri.parse("My URL"));
   var resBody = json.decode(res.body);
   print(resBody);
  }

 List<Event> _events = [];
 String selectedEvent;

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  final json = jsonDecode(getSWData().toString());
  _events = json.map<Welcome>((item) => Welcome.fromJson(item)).toList();
  selectedEvent = _events[0].titreCourtEvenement;

return new Scaffold(
  body: new Center(
    child: new Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
        DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
          child: new DropdownButton<String>(
            hint: new Text("Select Region"),
            value: selectedEvent,
            isDense: true,
            onChanged: (String newValue) {
              setState(() {
                selectedEvent = newValue;
              });
              print(selectedEvent);
            },
            items: _events.map((Event map) {
              return new DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                value: map.idEvenement,
                child: new Text(map.titreCourtEvenement,
                    style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.black)),
              );
            }).toList(),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
 );
}
```

Json Data,

```
[
 {
"idEvenement": "264",
"titreCourtEvenement": "THE 10th SANTORINI CONFERENCE",
"titreEvenement": "THE 10th SANTORINI CONFERENCEThe Odyssey from hope to Practice: Patient first",
"idLangue": "2",
"nomLangue": "English",
"flagLangue": "en",
"idSociete": "23",
"dateDebutEvenement": "2022-05-23 07:00:00",
"dateFinEvenement": "2022-05-26 23:00:00",
"archiverEvenement": "0",
"masquerEvenement": "0",
"isAdhesion": "0",
"idUser": "6",
"imageAgendaEvenement": "https://preprod.comnyou.net/files/2020/06/1592399280_santorini-vignette-insc.jpg",
"imageLogo": "https://preprod.comnyou.net/files/2021/02/santorini-vignette2022.jpg"
},
{
"idEvenement": "309",
"titreCourtEvenement": "SEUD 2021",
"titreEvenement": "The 7th Congress of the Society of Endometriosis and Uterine Disorders",
"idLangue": "2",
"nomLangue": "English",
"flagLangue": "en",
"idSociete": "2",
"dateDebutEvenement": "2021-12-08 07:00:00",
"dateFinEvenement": "2021-12-11 23:00:00",
"archiverEvenement": "0",
"masquerEvenement": "0",
"isAdhesion": "0",
"idUser": "22",
"imageAgendaEvenement": "https://preprod.comnyou.net/files/2021/03/seud-vignette-2021.jpg",
"imageLogo": "https://preprod.comnyou.net/files/2021/03/seud-vignette-2021.jpg"
 }
]
```

and finally the error output:

Error: XMLHttpRequest error.
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/core_patch.dart 909:28

and this output on screen:

FormatExeption SynthaxError: Unexpected token I in JSON at position 0

Comment: Can you share your headers in request function?

Comment: I have no headers

Comment: Then you should add content-type and accept headers as application/json

Answer (score 0):

This issue is about `getSWData` function and `jsonDecode(getSWData().toString());`

1. In `getSWData` function, you can return List.

   ```
    Future<List<Event>> getSWData() async {
      var res = await http.get(Uri.parse("My URL"));
      return res.map((x) => Event.fromJson(x).toList();          
    }
   ```
2. `getSWData()` will return Future<List>. So, you should use `await getSWData()` to get the list data.
3. You should set different layouts for different states (when `_events = null` and when `_events = [...]`) and call init function in `initState()`.

   ```
    void initEvent() async{
      _events = await getSWData();
      selectedEvent = _events[0].titreCourtEvenement;
      this.setState(() {});
    }

    @override
    void initState() {
      super.initState();
      initEvent();
    }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

This line inside your `build` method is going to cause you issues, because you're performing `toString()` on the `Future` rather than the result of the `Future`, as `getSWData()` returns a `Future`:

```dart
final json = jsonDecode(getSWData().toString());
```

I've gone ahead and modified your `Test2` widget so that it uses a [`FutureBuilder`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html) widget in order to display the list of events in a [`DropdownButton`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/DropdownButton-class.html) widget when the HTTP request completes:

```dart
class Test2 extends StatefulWidget {
  const Test2({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _Test2State createState() => _Test2State();
}

class _Test2State extends State<Test2> {
  Future<List<Event>> _events;

  Event selectedEvent;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: FutureBuilder<List<Event>>(
        future: _events,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          final events = snapshot.data;

          if (events != null) {
            return Center(
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
                    child: DropdownButton<Event>(
                      hint: const Text("Select Region"),
                      value: selectedEvent ?? events[0],
                      isDense: true,
                      onChanged: (newValue) {
                        setState(() {
                          selectedEvent = newValue;
                        });
                      },
                      items: events.map((Event map) {
                        return DropdownMenuItem<Event>(
                          value: map,
                          child: Text(
                            map.titreCourtEvenement,
                            style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                          ),
                        );
                      }).toList(),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            );
          } else {
            return const Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _events = getSWData();
  }
}

Future<List<Event>> getSWData() async {
  // var res = await get(Uri.parse("My URL"));
  // var resBody = json.decode(res.body) as List;
  var resBody = json.decode(
    '[{"idEvenement":"264","titreCourtEvenement":"THE 10th SANTORINI CONFERENCE","titreEvenement":"THE 10th SANTORINI CONFERENCEThe Odyssey from hope to Practice: Patient first","idLangue":"2","nomLangue":"English","flagLangue":"en","idSociete":"23","dateDebutEvenement":"2022-05-23 07:00:00","dateFinEvenement":"2022-05-26 23:00:00","archiverEvenement":"0","masquerEvenement":"0","isAdhesion":"0","idUser":"6","imageAgendaEvenement":"https://preprod.comnyou.net/files/2020/06/1592399280_santorini-vignette-insc.jpg","imageLogo":"https://preprod.comnyou.net/files/2021/02/santorini-vignette2022.jpg"},{"idEvenement":"309","titreCourtEvenement":"SEUD 2021","titreEvenement":"The 7th Congress of the Society of Endometriosis and Uterine Disorders","idLangue":"2","nomLangue":"English","flagLangue":"en","idSociete":"2","dateDebutEvenement":"2021-12-08 07:00:00","dateFinEvenement":"2021-12-11 23:00:00","archiverEvenement":"0","masquerEvenement":"0","isAdhesion":"0","idUser":"22","imageAgendaEvenement":"https://preprod.comnyou.net/files/2021/03/seud-vignette-2021.jpg","imageLogo":"https://preprod.comnyou.net/files/2021/03/seud-vignette-2021.jpg"}]',
  ) as List;
  return resBody.map((x) => Event.fromJson(x)).toList();
}
```

The [`FutureBuilder`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html) widget will display a circular progress indicator whilst the HTTP request is fetching the list of events, then it will display a dropdown button with the list of events once complete.

Please note that you can safely remove the three hard-coded JSON lines and uncomment the two HTTP request lines in the `getSWData()` method, in order to make an actual HTTP request.

Finally, I would recommend taking a look at [this](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/networking/fetch-data) guide for more information and in-depth examples regarding fetching data from the internet in Flutter applications.